# How to solved "Flutter my query is executed twice"

Tags: laravel, flutter, zend-framework

### **Hello community**

My concern is the following. I have a mobile application on **Flutter** which is connected to an API on a server which I will name **S1** which also connects to a server which I will name **S2**.

- The mobile client is responsible for displaying a **catalog of
  products** the client selects his products to make a purchase when he
  validates the purchase, the data is sent to the server **S1**
- Which then **S1** sends a request to the server **S2** to record the
  sale  Once it's done the **S2** server responds to the **S1** server
  which then registers the client for a Raffle once it's
- And finally, **S1** server responds to the Mobile client and the
  process ends.

The problem is that at times when the internet connection is not stable, the S2 server does a double buy. That is to say, it does the same twice yet the client only did it once
I suspect the timeout between the mobile client, server s1 and server s2 but I'm not sure.

Can someone guide me please
Environment: Flutter(Mobile), Laravel(Server S1), Zend Framework(Server2)

Comment: Is it necessary to have S1 as a middle-server? As the record of sale is managed on S2. You can directly send request to S2. Once the server replies back about successful record. Then you can do another request about raffle register. 

And if raffle register is not an immediate task. It would be better to do it later as a cron job.

Comment: Initially we started on the principle that if the sales process fails then the registration for the raffle must also fail and vice versa, which is why we placed the S1 server in the middle.

Comment: Another concern is that there are sales (duplicate) in the database that have the same time to the nearest second.

Comment: I didn't get your second point fully but the first one will be automatically resolved as unless the sale is successfully registered you don't send anything to raffle registration server.